# Would this question about copying structs in Swift be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Edit: the original question was answered on StackOverflow, so I won't be deleting it or reposting it here.

---

A month ago, before this site existed, I had asked a question on StackOverflow which was fairly theoretical in nature and got no attention (low views, no votes up or down, no answers, not even any comments).  It's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76267194/what-really-happens-behind-the-scenes-when-you-copy-a-struct) about how Swift handles deep vs. shallow copies for a value type, and why the results differ slightly when I would expect them to be exactly the same.

Since Swift is a less common tag on StackOverflow (I believe it was only 4% of SO users as of last year's survey), any questions that aren't straightforward tend to sit unanswered for a very long time compared to the more popular tags. But, as *this particular question* could also be considered as being about an implementation decision in an existing programming language (which I saw [are on topic here](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96/are-questions-about-specific-languages-on-topic)), might it be more likely to be answered on this site?

If the community decides that the question is worthwhile and that it would fit here, I will delete the original and re-post the question on PLDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could, but the focus would be different.

On StackOverflow, as currently written, I interpreted it as "why does a copy not call `init`?" (and I have answered it accordingly). Here, it would make more sense to ask "why did Swift decide to make copying an internal operation rather than calling an `init`?" -- or, perhaps, asking why a language would more generally choose one or the other.

Comment: That is very helpful to know, that the question wouldn't have been suitable as-is but would require a reframing in terms of the rationale behind that particular design decision.  Thanks!